# Can I sort two related arrays in parallel using python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have two NumPy arrays with the shape (74395, 1) storing float values
where arr1[0] correlates to arr2[0] and so on.
I would like to sort them together in ascending order by the values
stored in the second array.

As an example:

```
arr1: [[1]
       [2]
       [3]]

arr2: [[6]
       [2]
       [4]]
```

wanted result:

```
arr1: [[2]
       [3]
       [1]]

arr2: [[2]
       [4]
       [6]]
```

How could I do that in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.argsort` with `numpy.take_along_axis`:

```
ind = arr2.argsort(axis=0)

np.take_along_axis(arr1, ind, axis=0)
np.take_along_axis(arr2, ind, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
(array([[2],
        [3],
        [1]]),
 array([[2],
        [4],
        [6]]))
```

Comment: Why bring a huge dependency like numpy into this…?

Comment: @deceze Given OP uses 2d arrays, I automatically assumed its `numpy` :P.

Comment: @Chris Correct - I am indeed using numpy arrays and won't get around it ^^.
Two things - In order for the changes to take effect I had to overwrite the variables.
so arr1 = np.take_along... etc.
Secondly, my arr1 values are all 0 after the transformation

Comment: @FLOROID You mean sorted arr1 starts with many zeros or they are all zeros (`(arr1 == 0).all() == True`)?

Comment: It must've been some weird bug, because after re-running the application the data is correctly sorted now as far as I can tell with this much data haha

Comment: @Chris to answer your question - yeah the entire array was at 0.0 and it still happens at random. Sometimes the values will be sorted correctly and other time it will just be an array filled with zeros

Comment: @FLOROID That's odd... I can't reproduce it. It may happen due to different dtypes (like assigning float to int array) but again, it's hard to tell :P

Comment: @FLOROID Many people (mistakenly) call Python lists arrays, so it wasn't clear what you were using. It's always a good idea to mention when your question is about a specific package. I've edited your question and tagged NumPy.

Answer (score 5):

`zip` the two together, sort, `zip` again to transpose the result, and destructure:

```
>>> arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> arr2 = [6, 2, 4]
>>> arr2, arr1 = zip(*sorted(zip(arr2, arr1)))
>>> arr1
(2, 3, 1)
>>> arr2
(2, 4, 6)
```